# How to parse file without using eval - PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any other way to parse the file without eval()? I'm trying to render the php code without using php tags inside index.gs and so far i can do it only with eval().  The problem is not only to parse vars, but custom template characters.

here is the sample of code below.

```
 $render = file_get_contents($this->file);

 $render = $this->parse_extends($render);
 $render = $this->parse_assets($render);
 $render = $this->parse_vars($render);
 $render = $this->parse_vars_skip($render);

  try {
        ob_start();
        eval('?>' . $render);
        $render = ob_get_contents();
    } finally {
        ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $render;
```

The return $render - return to View::class code for response

Comment: *"I'm trying to render the php code without using php tags"* – why…?

Comment: Maybe ``highlight_file`` http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If the `allow_url_include` directive is enabled in `php.ini`, then it’s possible to execute this code using

```
include "data://text/plain;base64," . base64_encode($render);
```

but this setting is disabled by default, and cannot be changed within user code, but only through editing the `php.ini` file; so unless explicitly enabled in `php.ini` (and there normally isn’t any good reason why it should be), then it isn’t really an option.

An alternative is to create a temporary file, write the code there, and then execute it using include:

```
$tempFilename = tempnam("/tmp", "MyTemplate");
file_put_contents($tempFilename, $render);
include $tempFilename;
unlink($tempFilename);
```

But both have similar issues and dangers to eval().

Comment: Yes I already tried second way, but it was not good  if you have only   layout.master.gs and index.gs  then yes but if you yield other files or include then  it's not good

Comment: The second one is honestly just `eval` but using the filesystem instead of RAM to store the code to be evaluated, which is kinda silly ;)